# Removing Vertical White Lines in ggplot Line Graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've produced a graph using ggplot and some data that represents the occurrence of specific management actions over the past decade. The graph looks great except for some vertical white spaces that appear within the plotted lines. Is there a way to remove these lines? I'm guessing they are caused by the grouping of my data (group=1). Any help would be appreciated. My code is below.

Also, I've used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951422/r-ggplot-and-facet-grid-how-to-control-x-axis-breaks) stackoverflow question as guidance.

```
library(scales)

# Build data frame.
a7.data <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2002/01/01"), as.Date("2013/05/01"),     by="day"))
a7.data$year <- as.numeric(format(as.Date(a7.data$date), format="%Y"))
a7.data$month <- as.numeric(format(as.Date(a7.data$date), format="%m"))
a7.data$day <- as.numeric(format(as.Date(a7.data$date), format="%d"))
a7.data$status <- "Yes"
a7.data$filler_value <- 0

# Edit data frame for dates in which the management action was "no".
a7.data$status[a7.data$date >= "2002/01/01" & a7.data$date < "2002/07/01"] <- "No"
a7.data$status[a7.data$date >= "2005/05/20" & a7.data$date < "2005/08/25"] <- "No"
a7.data$status[a7.data$date >= "2005/12/31" & a7.data$date < "2006/04/12"] <- "No"
a7.data$status[a7.data$date >= "2006/11/06" & a7.data$date < "2006/12/31"] <- "No"
a7.data$status[a7.data$date >= "2007/01/31" & a7.data$date < "2007/07/02"] <- "No"
a7.data$status[a7.data$date >= "2008/02/01" & a7.data$date < "2009/08/11"] <- "No"
a7.data$status[a7.data$date >= "2010/02/28" & a7.data$date < "2010/03/15"] <- "No"
a7.data$status[a7.data$date >= "2010/05/09" & a7.data$date < "2010/07/07"] <- "No"

# Create a new column that creates a dummy year with which to plot the data in ggplot using faceting.
a7.data <- transform(a7.data, doy = as.Date(paste(1970, month, day, sep="/")))

# Custom colors.
ccolors <- c("#086CA2", "#FF8B00")

# ggplot code.
bb <- ggplot(a7.data, aes(doy, filler_value)) + 
geom_line(aes(color=status, group=1), size=15, alpha=0.9) + 
scale_x_date(label=date_format("%b"), breaks = "month") + 
xlab("") + ylab("") + facet_grid(year~., scales="free") + 
theme_bw() + theme(axis.text.y=element_blank()) + 
theme(axis.ticks.y=element_blank()) + 
scale_color_manual(values=ccolors, name="Article VII Restrictions?")

# Display plot.
bb
```

Comment: hi, are you referring to the white space to the left and right of `Jan`

Comment: I should have been more clear. I was referring to the very thin white spaced within the color blocks. SimonO101 solved my problem by recommending I use geom_linerange instead of geom_line to create contiguous color blocks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interesting plot! I think if I understand your problem you either need

- to add an `expand = c(0,0)` to `scale_x_date` to get rid of the space
  at the boundaries
- and/or use `geom_linerange` to make contiguous colour blocks

But you need to specify both a `ymin` and a `ymax` value to use `geom_linerange`. `filler_value` seems to be a natural choice for `ymin` so lets make `a7.data$filler_value2 <- 1` to be our `ymax` and use a `geom_linerange` and include an `expand` argument:

```
a7.data$filler_value2 <- 1
bb <- ggplot(a7.data, aes(x = doy)) + 
geom_linerange( aes(ymin = filler_value , ymax = filler_value2 , color=status, group=1), size=15, alpha=0.9) + 
scale_x_date(label=date_format("%b"), breaks = "month" , expand = c(0,0)) + 
xlab("") + ylab("") + facet_grid(year~., scales="free") + 
theme_bw() + theme(axis.text.y=element_blank()) + 
theme(axis.ticks.y=element_blank()) + 
scale_color_manual(values=ccolors, name="Article VII Restrictions?")

# Display plot.
bb
```

If I make those changes I get a plot that looks like this...
[image]

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks for your help. I'm still learning all the capabilities of ggplot2 and haven't really looked into geom_linerange. Lesson learned!

Comment: I did not know about `geom_linerange`, nice!